# My IBMQ job hangs forever?

Tags: qiskit, programming, ibm-q-experience

I am running a very simple script just to learn how to use IBMQ, but my job will hang indefinitely and I am forced to terminate it.

```
from qiskit import *
from qiskit.compiler import transpile, assemble
from qiskit import IBMQ
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, execute, BasicAer
import logging


logging.basicConfig(filename='log',level=logging.DEBUG)

IBMQ.load_account()
provider = IBMQ.get_provider(hub='ibm-q', group='open', project='main')

#SELECT A BACKEND
backend = provider.get_backend('ibmq_qasm_simulator')

#ALGO
qr = QuantumRegister(3)
cr = ClassicalRegister(3)
circuit = QuantumCircuit(qr, cr)
circuit.x(qr[0])
circuit.x(qr[1])
circuit.ccx(qr[0], qr[1], qr[2])
circuit.cx(qr[0], qr[1])
circuit.measure(qr, cr)

print('About to run job')   
job = execute(circuit, backend)
print('Job Finished')
result = job.result()
counts = result.get_counts(circuit)
print(counts)
```

In an attempt to debug, I am using "logging.basicConfig" which stops at:

```
"websocket._connect:DEBUG:2020-09-16 11:26:57,813: Starting new websocket connection: wss://wss.quantum-computing.ibm.com/jobs/5f6258f09234fe0012dbd748/status/v/1"
```

When I go to my IBMQ home page it says that the job has run successfully. It is only at the line `result = job.result()` that it fails.

So it seems that the websocket is hanging forever. I'd appreciate any help I can get to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `execute` is non-blocking. That means that it will return after sending the job, but not necessarily with the result. In your code, you should wait for the status of the job to be `DONE`:

```
print('About to run job')   
job = execute(circuit, backend)
job.status()
```

```
JobStatus.QUEUED
```

After waiting some time:

```
job.status()
```

```
JobStatus.DONE
```

Then, `job.result()` will work.

Comment: This works! Although, I am looking to improve my method if possible. I have added the following loop to check when the job is done. Is there a better way to do this? 

while str(job.status()) != 'JobStatus.DONE':
    print(job.status())

Comment: `job.result()` actually waits for the job to finish (so the result can be retrieved), and that's why it appears to "hang". If you want to have a separate step to wait for the job, you can use `job.wait_for_final_state()`, which also supports a callback function that you can use to say print the current status. It uses websockets, which is more efficient than polling with `job.status()`

Comment: Your explanation makes sense to me, but unfortunately it is not working. I am using "job.wait_for_final_state(timeout=1,callback='job_status')" but I still get hung up on the same websocket as previously. So far, the only thing to work is the inefficient method of using a while loop with job.status(). I very much appreciate your help so far and would welcome any more suggestions you may have.

Comment: Which version of `qiskit-ibmq-provider` are you using? There was a problem with websockets on Windows + Python 3.8 (see https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-ibmq-provider/issues/691) that was fixed in a recent release. 

By the way, the argument for `callback` needs to be a function.

Comment: And we now are at the heart of the issue. As you suspected, I had been using an older version which was clearly bugged.

Answer (score 2):

To add on to the previous answer, if you want to see the progress of your job in real time, you can try the following:

```
from qiskit.tools.monitor import job_monitor
job_monitor(job)
```

job_monitor shows you ever step, including job initialization, validation, being queued, to running and completion.